# Inconsistent event firing on mapbox zoomstart and zoomend

Tags: event-handling, zooming, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on mapbox js-gl, version 1.7.0. I have tied the showing and hiding of a crosshairs div on my page to the zoomstart and zoomend events.

```
map.on('zoomstart', function (e)
{
    $("#crosshairs-container").show();
    console.log("Zooming started...");
});

map.on('zoomend', function (e)
{
    $("#crosshairs-container").hide();
    console.log("Zooming finished...");
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    renderMap();
});
```

The problem is: the referenced div doesn't appear and disappear reliably and consistently.

**On desktop (Linux/Chrome):** the mouse wheel's individual "incremental jumps" (most mice have them, if not all of the nowadays) are sometimes registered as the zoomend event, and sometimes not. 
This means, that sometimes zooming finishes after one "wobble" of the mouse wheel - even though I'm still zooming by continuing to turn the mouse wheel. Other times, the zooming continues as I continue to turn the mouse wheel - the behaviour I'd expect.

**On mobile (Android/Chrome):** Similar behaviour, though, here, the crosshairs overlay pretty much disappears completely while zooming (in or out).

I have observed that, when zooming in and out (trying to reproduce and observe this behaviour) several times over the same part of the map (which has already loaded and added layers), the desktop seems to "find its groove", so to speak.

My question is: since it's rather unlikely that I have used the wrong events - I don't think this is a coding issue - has anyone else seen this behaviour ? Is this a hardware issue, in the sense that the pinch zoom on mobile does things "intermittently", as does a "incremental wobbles" mouse wheel ? So what - to the user - looks and feels continuous, is actually, behind the scenes, many inidividually triggered events "stitched together" ?

Incidentally, the drag events work flawlessly on desktop & mobile.

Comment: After some research, I think it has to do with the browser/mouse hardware "spamming" the event too many times. I looking at https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce to sort this problem out. Will let you know if it works out.

Comment: Yeah, I'd look at using debounce, and also possibly listening to a different event, such as `moveend`.

Comment: @SteveBennett could you give me a quick pointer on how to actually override/debounce the map.on('zoomend') event ? Not sure what the syntax should be. window.addEventListener("bla", bla, false); surely isn't it.

Comment: Don't debounce the event itself, debounce your handler...inside the event. So the event triggers a million times, but only a few of them actually make it through to your handler.

Comment: @SteveBennett thanks a lot! I was trying many ways to get this to work yet what you suggested never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by switching from the `dragstart` end `dragend` events to the `movestart` and `moveend` events. This seems to avoid all problems, including having to debounce or throttle the event handlers.
Thanks to @Steve Bennett for the tip.